# TypeError: a float is require

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hello I have this code :

```
import math
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2.79e-06,2.47e-06,0.000122,3.9e-05,0.000527,9.41e-06,3.11e-05,4.63e-05,0.000749,0.000499,0.000174,0.000984,0.000912,5.86e-05,0.000344,0.000754,0.000267,2.53e-06,8.73e-05,0.000791,1.69e-06,7.56e-05,0.001,3.1e-06,0.000305,2.4e-06,6.37e-06,3.25e-07,6.67e-05,0.000167,0.000954,2.36e-07,3.8e-06,0.000337,8.1e-06,1.68e-05,0.000332,3.64e-06,"0,00002",5.97e-06,0.000808,2.34e-06,0.000121,0.000972,2.59e-05,0.000761,8.76e-05,0.000253,0.000819,7.88e-06,5.04e-05,1.75e-05,5.83e-05,0.000271,3.18e-06,3.29e-05,0.000979,0.000925,2.55e-05,0.000347,0.000269,9.51e-06,5.54e-06,7.18e-05,1.44e-05,8.42e-09,1.86e-05,0.000377,1.68e-05,0.000991,4.69e-06,9.87e-05,4.45e-05,4.05e-06,6.76e-05,5.66e-06,6.51e-06,3.76e-06,6.44e-05,2.91e-09,0.000565,9.18e-06,0.0003,0.0002,9.43e-05,8.57e-06,6.32e-05,"0,000004",5.18e-06,0.000181,0.000999,1.67e-05,0.000941,6.49e-05,0.000141,4.07e-06,2.68e-06,0.000407,1.47e-05,5.2e-06,6.53e-06,0.000462,1.38e-05,0.000794,3.32e-07,2.19e-06,0.000432,0.000156
])
b = np.array([math.log10(i) for i in a])
```

And I don't know why but I get this error : `TypeError: a float is require`

How can I solve this ?

Thank you !

Comment: The list you pass to `np.array` when you create `a` contains two strings.

Comment: You've got malformed data. i.e. '0,00002'  You'll want to fix those -- you can check by force typing array a to floating types (i.e.` a=a.astype(np.float64).  If you can force array a to all floating types you should be good to go to create array b.

Comment: After fixing the string problem,  `b=numpy.log10(a)` is a more efficient and readable way to do the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` contain `"0,000004"` that is an string.

You should remove all the string in the list you are passing to `np.array`.

To identify all the indexes and values of the list that contain values that aren't float you can do:

```
l = [2.79e-06,2.47e-06,0.000122,3.9e-05,0.000527,9.41e-06,3.11e-05,4.63e-05,0.000749,0.000499,0.000174,0.000984,0.000912,5.86e-05,0.000344,0.000754,0.000267,2.53e-06,8.73e-05,0.000791,1.69e-06,7.56e-05,0.001,3.1e-06,0.000305,2.4e-06,6.37e-06,3.25e-07,6.67e-05,0.000167,0.000954,2.36e-07,3.8e-06,0.000337,8.1e-06,1.68e-05,0.000332,3.64e-06,"0,00002",5.97e-06,0.000808,2.34e-06,0.000121,0.000972,2.59e-05,0.000761,8.76e-05,0.000253,0.000819,7.88e-06,5.04e-05,1.75e-05,5.83e-05,0.000271,3.18e-06,3.29e-05,0.000979,0.000925,2.55e-05,0.000347,0.000269,9.51e-06,5.54e-06,7.18e-05,1.44e-05,8.42e-09,1.86e-05,0.000377,1.68e-05,0.000991,4.69e-06,9.87e-05,4.45e-05,4.05e-06,6.76e-05,5.66e-06,6.51e-06,3.76e-06,6.44e-05,2.91e-09,0.000565,9.18e-06,0.0003,0.0002,9.43e-05,8.57e-06,6.32e-05,"0,000004",5.18e-06,0.000181,0.000999,1.67e-05,0.000941,6.49e-05,0.000141,4.07e-06,2.68e-06,0.000407,1.47e-05,5.2e-06,6.53e-06,0.000462,1.38e-05,0.000794,3.32e-07,2.19e-06,0.000432,0.000156]
print([(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(l) if type(v) != float])
```

Comment: That is stating the problem and is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because some elements are in the string form and the decimal point are marked by comma instead of decimal points. You can solve this by replacing comma with decimal point and typecasting to float as in below:

```
import math
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2.79e-06,2.47e-06,0.000122,3.9e-05,0.000527,9.41e-06,3.11e-05,4.63e-05,0.000749,0.000499,0.000174,0.000984,0.000912,5.86e-05,0.000344,0.000754,0.000267,2.53e-06,8.73e-05,0.000791,1.69e-06,7.56e-05,0.001,3.1e-06,0.000305,2.4e-06,6.37e-06,3.25e-07,6.67e-05,0.000167,0.000954,2.36e-07,3.8e-06,0.000337,8.1e-06,1.68e-05,0.000332,3.64e-06,"0,00002",5.97e-06,0.000808,2.34e-06,0.000121,0.000972,2.59e-05,0.000761,8.76e-05,0.000253,0.000819,7.88e-06,5.04e-05,1.75e-05,5.83e-05,0.000271,3.18e-06,3.29e-05,0.000979,0.000925,2.55e-05,0.000347,0.000269,9.51e-06,5.54e-06,7.18e-05,1.44e-05,8.42e-09,1.86e-05,0.000377,1.68e-05,0.000991,4.69e-06,9.87e-05,4.45e-05,4.05e-06,6.76e-05,5.66e-06,6.51e-06,3.76e-06,6.44e-05,2.91e-09,0.000565,9.18e-06,0.0003,0.0002,9.43e-05,8.57e-06,6.32e-05,"0,000004",5.18e-06,0.000181,0.000999,1.67e-05,0.000941,6.49e-05,0.000141,4.07e-06,2.68e-06,0.000407,1.47e-05,5.2e-06,6.53e-06,0.000462,1.38e-05,0.000794,3.32e-07,2.19e-06,0.000432,0.000156
])
b = np.array([math.log10(float(i.replace(",",'.'))) for i in a])
print (b)
```